# Does anyone know how to download a project from nitrous.io?

Tags: ruby, download, nitrousio

I made an ruby web application on nitrous.io, the tool is very nice and it helped a lot but now I want to download ther project in my computer and I didn't found any option to do that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download and upload projects by any of the following options:

1. Utilize [Nitrous Desktop](http://www.nitrous.io/desktop) to Sync your files locally.
2. Upload your project to Github, and pull the project from there. [Here is a guide](http://help.nitrous.io/github-add-key/) on adding the SSH key to Github if needed.
3. Upload the content via SCP. To do this, you will need to [add an SSH Key](http://help.nitrous.io/ssh-add/) to your account.

Next, run this command on your local machine, replacing {PORT} with the port # assigned to your Nitrous.IO box, and also changing `usw1` with the proper region found in the SSH URI of your [boxes page](https://www.nitrous.io/app#/boxes).

To Upload:

```
scp -P{PORT} -r path/to/yourFolder action@usw1-2.nitrousbox.com:~/workspace
```

To Download:

```
scp -P{PORT} -r action@usw1-2.nitrousbox.com:~/workspace path/to/yourLocalFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the service, but apparently they offer ssh access. Then you can use scp to copy the files to your machine. Anyway, probably you should ask their support...

...post a summary of their answer here and close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to store your project in a Git repository and then push this repository to an external host. You will then be able to clone your project from the external repository to any machine you want.

Personally, I use Bitbucket ([Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) as it is free and very easy to set up. Have a look at the tutorials there.

Answer (score 0):

ok replying really late but I hope this will help anyone still looking for this. Here is how I download stuff from nitrous, no desktop utility download needed, and no ssh/scp or adding keys.
What you do is, simply make a archive for the folder you want to download by

```
tar -zcvf myarchive.tar.gz mydir/
```

now you got a *.gz file right? Whichever folder your gz file is in, be there and type:

```
python3.3 -m http.server 8080
```

you just started a cute little http server ready to serve you your download, now from the Preview menu click "Port 8080", this opens a new browser tab showing your gz file in the file listing (sample url http://yourboxes.apse1.nitrousbox.com:8080/). Now you can click your gz file and it will start downloading. Once done with the download, press Ctrl+C on the terminal to terminate the http server.

This is not limited to nitrous, you can make this work on many online VMs like cloud9 etc.